# declaring array of vectors in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am new to cpp STL I have a doubt regarding array of vectors 
when we declare array of vectors like `vectors <int> arr[100];`
we can also say this as a 2-D matrix .But we if talk about 2-D arrays (`int prr[100][100]`) then `prr[0]` then it will print the address of first array in 0th row
Basically i want to ask why we are declaring `vector <int> arr[100]` because `arr[0]` will also store address of array at 0th array
we should declare like `vector <int*> arr[100]` for declaring array of vectors

Comment: FWIW, if you want a matrix you use a `std::vector<data_type>` in a class and fake that it has multiple dimensions using math.  This gives you the most performance.

Comment: There is no such thing as `vectors<int>` in the C++ standard library.   However, `std::vector<int> arr[100]` is an array of one hundred `std::vector<int>`, which can be used - with care - AS IF it is a 2-D matrix.  The number of elements of each `std::vector<int>` depends on what the program does.

Answer (score 3):

> But we if talk about 2-D arrays (`int prr[100][100]`) then `prr[0]` then it will print the address of first array in 0th row

That is true to some extent and in some contexts.

`prr[0]` is an object of type `int [100]` -- an array of 100 `int`s.

In some contexts, `prr[0]` decays to a pointer to its first element, however it is not always true.

`sizeof(prr[0])` will be `100 * sizeof(int)`.
`&prr[0]` will be of type `int (*)[100)`, pointer to "array of 100 `int`s", not `int**`.

In contrast,

> Basically i want to ask why we are declaring `vector <int> arr[100]` because `arr[0]` will also store address of array at 0th array we should declare like`vector <int*> arr[100]` for declaring array of vectors

No, `arr[0]` will not store the address of the array at 0-th array. `arr[0]` is of type `std::vector<int>`. It's simple as that. Unlike an array, an object of type `std::vector<int>` does not decay to a pointer to the first element of the object in any context. Hence any further comparisons with `int*` does not make sense.